# Downloading a file to modify it on Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

So I am using S3 to store basically audio files, I stream those files with cloudfront.  I need to modify the metadata of those files (not the metadata of the s3 object, but the tags of the music), or convert those files to another format (mp3 to m4a, etc).  So the way I see it I need to download these files to my server, modify the files or transcode this files, and reupload the files.

I see some ways to do this but I have some doubts on which is the correct way or best way to do it.

So one way would be to download the file with the following code

```
S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
        System.out.println("Content-Type: " + object.getObjectMetadata());
        //displayTextInputStream(object.getObjectContent());
```

And I could use File to write the file to my server.
My question heres is how do I obtain just the file name from the S3Object, I was looking in the metadata and tried to use getContentDisposition(), but it returns null, looking directly in AWS Console I see the proper name of the file without the path.

The other idea I have is to use cloudfront to download the file, creating a download distribution.

Can I work directly with and inputstream to modify the metadata?

Comment: Sorry I hit save before I could  finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can save this file under any name you choose, just like any other file you download through HTTP.

However, as you mentioned in your question:

```
String disposition = object.getObjectMetadata().getContentDisposition()
```

Should give you the optional Content-Disposition HTTP header, which specifies presentation information for the object such as the recommended file-name for the object to be saved as.

This function returns `null` if the Content-Disposition header hasn't been set.

This is from Amazon online documentation: For more information on how the Content-Disposition header affects HTTP client behavior, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1.

Comment: When I print  disposition I get null

Comment: I suppose that your problem is in fact uploading the file back to S3, while overriding the previous version, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am think on workarounds for this, but I thought I might be able to get the filename without the path

Comment: So my option here is maybe regular expression right?